# how to perform events when a checkbox is checked/unchecked in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following jquery code which works fine.

```
$('#onlyTwo').click(function() {
                $("#textarea3").attr("disabled", true);
                $("#textarea4").attr("disabled", true);
                $("#radio3").attr("disabled", true);
                $("#radio4").attr("disabled", true);
                return true;
            });
```

This is making some fields disabled when 'onlyTwo' checkbox is clicked.  How can i make these fields enabed again when 'onlyTwo' checkbox is unchecked...

basically i want to know how to find out whether a checkbox is checked or not

Answer (score 18, accepted):

or

```
$('#onlyTwo').click(function(){
   var stuff = $("#textarea3,  #textarea4, #radio3, #radio4");
   stuff.attr("disabled", $(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

Comment: if($(this).is(":checked")} had to be changed to if($(this).is(":checked")) but other than that it works! thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#onlyTwo').change(function() {
    $('.disableMe').attr('disabled', $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

so you need to add 'disableMe' class to all the inputs, textareas, selects... that you wish to disable.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#onlyTwo').click(function() {
     var elements = ['textarea3', 'textarea4', 'radio3', 'radio4'];
     var checked = $(this).attr('checked');

     jQuery.each(elements, function(element) {
       if (checked) {
         $('#'+element).attr('disabled', true);
       } else {
         $('#'+element).removeAttr('disabled');
       }
     });
})
```

Thats a simple solution to toggle the disabled attribute on all the elements you want when `$('#onlyTwo')` is checked.

Fixed array problems, lol this was full of little bugs.

Comment: wow, thats awesome. where are u checking for 'toggle'? also, i am getting a syntax error on ')};'

Comment: syntax error is coming when you are closing the second function. 

on the second last line of the code you posted

Comment: I'm getting a 'array is not defined
Line 40' error now at runtime :(

Comment: i dont think that will work, atleast in IE, ie only cares if the disabled attribute is there in order to disable the element, it does not care about the value of it

Comment: he must have typed that really fast, array line should be var elements = ['textarea3', 'textarea4', 'radio3', 'radio4'];

Comment: Ah thanks mkoryak, I was coding in PHP while answering this question, didn't even think about it.

Comment: I had tried that. I hate to be asking simple syntax questions but i suck at jquery :(.  Now it says elements.each is not a function....